# Custom array repeating function

Tags: php, arrays, function, range

I want to concatenate two similar `range` (for unicode number conversion purpose),to make an array like this:

```
   $nums = [
    0=> 0,
    1=> 1,
    2=> 2,
    3=> 3,
    4=> 4,
    5=> 5,
    6=> 6,
    7=> 7,
    8=> 8,
    9=> 9,
    10=> 0,
    11=> 1,
    12=> 2,
    13=> 3,
    14=> 4,
    15=> 5,
    16=> 6,
    17=> 7,
    18=> 8,
    19=> 9
    ];
```

I can do this simply with concatenating like this code:

```
$nums=array_merge(range(0,9),range(0,9));
```

But I am looking for more efficient or a dedicated PHP function for this job.
I will appriciate any kind of method or mention dedicated function existence.

Comment: More efficient is **C**

Comment: You could have that in a function, like so: [https://eval.in/599535](https://eval.in/599535). That way you can select the start, the end and the quantity easily.

Comment: I don't know what your goal is, but it sounds like you need the Modulo operator, not any functions.

Comment: It is  part of unicode numbers(numbers not in english) converter.

Comment: @FirstOne +1 both for your code and `eval.in` Presentation.

Comment: Are the 2 ranges always the same? Are there only 2 ranges each time you need the array?

Comment: Yes @thelogix ,but im searching for fastest way.Maybe direct assigning is the fastest one, but i am interested in the most fastest PHP code for this job( Maybe it would not the fastest one because of patsing)

Answer (score 1):

**Update** *(because version was not reliably reproducibly faster than OP's original code.)*

Does it have to be an array merge? Based on your answer to my comment above, i can assume that the 2 ranges are always the same. Ie. its just a repeating range / sequence.

You also mention, that it is for conversion, so i guess its a lookup table.

```
$input = 11;
$nums = array_merge(range(0,9),range(0,9))
echo $nums[$input];

// This will output 1
```

Assuming this is the purpose, giving it eg. 11 as input and getting the 1 for result, you can gain much speed by doing this without arrays.

Assume that range is 0, 9, and 11 again as input:

```
$input = 11;

$rmin = 0;
$rmax = 9;

$rmax = $rmax + 1 - $rmin;
$output = ($input % $rmax) + $rmin;   

echo $output;

// This will output 1
```

the $input => $output values will match your array version excactly.You can also rmin and rmax to match whatever range you want.

Speed-wise its a little hard to compare because its 2 different approaches, but 100.000 times of

```
nums = array_merge(range(0,9),range(0,9));
```

is 0.272 seconds here, and 100.000 rounds of my code above (without the "echo") gives 0.021 seconds.

Comment: +1 : for your time and algorithm. I check both your code and `$nums = array_merge(range(0,9),range(0,9));` with `100,000` iterations . my code takes 0.20 sec and yours takes 0.25 sec.(as your awareness) and simply assigning 20 elements array in that itterations takes just about half(0.089 sec)

Comment: In addition to my last comment ,I think we should not calculate time after main algorithm, specially `print` function is more time consuming and can make big tolerances.If you make second `microtime()` before `print` function , you will get more noticeable results

Comment: I just tested using $total = microtime(1); print "new: ".$total."\n"; instead. Makes no difference at all.

Comment: I tested both codes on my pc and you can see the test code and my outputs on [https://eval.in/599867](https://eval.in/599867)

Comment: UPDATED: I add your edited code too. its about 8% more efficient than your previous code and a little less efficient than simple `array_merge()`. Look here [https://eval.in/599876](https://eval.in/599876)

Comment: Thats a weird difference. Maybe different php version or something local.

Comment: I will so glad if you upload these codes result from your computer.

Comment: Your code from https://eval.in/ gives me, on my computer: 0.26929116249084
0.34282088279724
0.2298538684845

Comment: Thanks man, numbers are close. on your pc your code take lower time, Its better that i mention i tested on virtual linux with php 5.6.22.

Comment: php 5.5.9 on ubuntu 14.04 on a laptop

Comment: Maybe affected from some version improvements, or other parameters.